# how to publish on ovi store application which uses library from extras repository?

Tags: widget, maemo, n900, qt-maemo, ovi

how to publish on ovi store application which uses library from extras repository ?

I tried create a homescreen widget and I stopped on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Extras repository is enabled in N900 by default, so in case your application is free and list the library as a dependency (you should list the library in Depends: field
of your binary package in the debian/control file
http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps)
then there should be no problem during installation.
Unfortunately, this won't work for paid applications as Application Manager doesn't deal
package dependencies unless they are already installed on the phone. In this case you would need ship library inside your package taking into account possible conflicts, or link library
statically to your application, or split your application into two parts: engine and data, making engine free and depending to the library, while data package will be paid. The latter makes installation more complicated and should be considered appropriately.